# Progress Tracker with 2 levels

Tags: wizard, progress-bar, multi-step, progress

I'm currently designing a step-by-step wizard, where the interface tells the user which section of the wizard he/she is visiting, using [Progress Trackers](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/what-is-the-name-of-the-breadcrumb-workflow-ui-component), like the image below.

The user can navigate through each Step, back and forward and also jump between Steps that are already complete (ex: on Step 3, jump to Step 1)

[image]

Now the challenge is that those steps have sub-steps inside, for example, for the user to complete the Step 3, he/she needs to fill four sub-steps that are related with that Step 3, like this:

[image]

**My question is...**

*Having Progress Tracker with 2 levels, which the user can navigate through, is a flow that is familiar for the user? If so, is there any usability issue that I should be aware of?*

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is a familiar flow, but it can work.

There are a few points.

- Make sure your hierarchy between main steps and sub steps is very clear. Users must not think there are more steps than there really are.
- Also make sure there's a clear difference between a completed and an in progress step (like your image already has).

The above mentioned points could look something like this.

[image]

Another solution might be to make the substeps part of the main steps using a progress bar. See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Users don't really care about *discrete* progress

Rather than showing sub-steps that tell the user exactly which one they're on, I'd recommend implementing a progress bar on each section of the wizard. I'm envisioning the `Step 1` box with a progress bar immediately below it or within it (maybe as a background?).

This sacrifices letting users know the exact number of actions they need to take, but in some cases, I would argue that this is better as it seems like fewer steps are necessary.

Comment: Ok, I just added to the question that the user can jump between steps (check 2nd paragraph). I believe this will important to share since the Steps, although indicate progress, also serve as "shortcut" to jump between steps

Answer (score 0):

It is not something that I have seen before, but I think it could work. As a suggestion, consider if you can have left and top navigation, especially when they are too many sub-steps. I think this is model that more people are used to it.

Something like the following images:

[image]

Or

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: This is very confusing. There is no association to what is on the left and what's on the top.

Comment: @Majo0od Thanks for your comment. What about if I place the steps on top and the substeps on the left? Is it more clear now? all ideas for improvement are more than welcome